# .NET Microframework SDK with VS 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, embedded, .net-micro-framework

I am trying to get started developing using the .NET Micro Framework but appear to have hit a road block. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and it will not let me install the SDK because I do not have Visual Studio 2005. I downloaded the SDK from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=EB0EF2A6-03E2-402C-89A4-A636BD0080C5&displaylang=en) link.

I know this is not truly a programming question but it is definitely holding me back from getting started. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the .NET Microframework 3.0 Beta to work in Visual Studio 2008 (as far as I know):

http://connect.microsoft.com/netmf/

Comment: The link says beta but it's really RC0 (and requires VS2008 SP1)

Comment: Right Right, This makes sense. I was a little confused as I had heard several different version numbers being thrown around. Thank you for your help.